# Add row data to total,without showing row values SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, bids, report-builder2.0

I am relatively new to SSRS. This is a Dynamics CRM report. My scenario is that I have a 15 truck drivers. I have created a report that shows their number of trips and the miles driven. I can sum the miles and get the total number of miles for each driver. 
What I want is just the driver name and the total number of miles driven.I am not sure how to get that calculation done in SSRS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards

SR

Answer (score 0):

It will be straight forward if your dataset just returns the data you need - the driver name and the total numbers.

But if your dataset returns the detailed data, not totals, then you can just hide the detail row of the tablix: right click on the detail row header -> Row Visibility... -> select the "Hidden" radio button. With that, I'm assuming your report already has the grouping by Driver and shows the total miles.

Best regards,

~Alexey